# how to change the unix PATH value in php environment

Tags: php, apache, mamp

I've recently installed a composer library which heavily relies on the unix `$PATH` variable being set correctly.

Usually this isn't an issue, but unfortunately there is no way for me to override the functionality of this library.

Currently, when I echo out the `$PATH`, **PHP** will spit out:

> `/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:.`

When it needs to be:

> `/usr/local/bin`

After searching around for a bit, I came across the [dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) library as a potential solution using `$_ENV["PATH"] = "..."`. However, this didn't work.

Following that, I attempted to simply execute this at the top of my initialisation file:

```
exec("PATH=/usr/local/bin")
echo shell_exec("echo $PATH");
```

Also to no avail.

So, how would one do this within **PHP**? Specifically in a **MAMP** environment on OSX. Is there a config setting I can change?

Comment: For OSX, try editing /etc/paths

Comment: @KenLee Hmm, interestingly, `/etc/paths` shows the _correct_ paths. Looks like this is a **MAMP** environment issue.

Comment: You need to change and export the variable in the process that spawns all php processes. Depending on how your configured your http server those might be the apache children (if you are using php as a module) or separate script processes (if you are using php as a cgi extension) or children of the fcgi server (if you are using php in fastcgi manner). Environment variables are inherited to child processes. Such approach may have unwanted sire effects though, since other processes might also rely on that variables content.

Comment: In that case (due to MAMP), check your ~/.bash_profile (or .zshrc ) too

Comment: It depends on how this library reads $PATH.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it with PHP in the PHP environment, you can use [putenv()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.putenv.php).

```
putenv("PATH=/usr/local/bin");
```

Or if you just want to prepend your path

```
$oldpath = getenv('PATH');
putenv("PATH=/usr/local/bin:$oldpath");
```